# Extend jQuery's slideUp() to remove elements after animation

Tags: jquery

I'm looking to extend the jQuery's `slideUp()` method to remove the elements after the slide animation and apply the callback **after** the elements have been removed.

So far I have this method to remove the elements:

```
$.fn.slideUpRemove = function () {
    var args = arguments;
    return this.each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        $.fn.slideUp.apply($this, args).promise().done(function () {
            $this.remove();
        });
    });
};
```

But this runs the callback before `remove()` when called like:

```
$('div').slideUpRemove(function () {
    console.log($('div').length);
});
```

What would be the best approach to apply the callback after the elements have been removed from the DOM?

Here's a **[demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/koala_dev/SQCU9/1)** with the current code for you to play with

**EDIT**

My original idea was to create basically an extension of `slideUp()` that would perform in the same way, that is with the same options and running the callback for each element, however after some thought I realized a callback per element wouldn't be of much use because there wouldn't be any element to set as the context. On that note, a single callback run after the elements have been removed seems like the best approach.

Comment: The callback should be called once for each element? Or once when all animations are complete?

Comment: @undefined since I would like it to behave mostly as `slideUp()`, ideally it should be once per element, but if that turns out to be too much trouble, I'll settle for the other option

Comment: Just... execute the callback after you remove the element. since removing an element is a synchronous action, you can literally just execute it on the following line. Don't forget to remove the callback from the passed in arguments.

Comment: @KevinB so you suggest I apply the callback outside of the custom method `slideUpRemove()`?

Comment: no.. literally after .remove.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in case that the handler should be called once when all elements have been removed:

```
$.fn.slideUpRemove = function (d, c) {
    var _this = this,
        duration = $.isNumeric(d) || $.isPlainObject(d) ? d : 400,
        callback = $.isFunction(c) ? c : d;

    return this.slideUp(duration).promise().done(function () {
        _this.remove();
        if ($.isFunction(callback)) callback.call();
    });
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6sKRC/

Comment: This would work if I pass the callback as a single argument right? but then I can't pass the options for the slideUp animation

Comment: @koala_dev Yes, do you want to pass duration and callback? These 2 arguments?

Comment: I see you updated your answer to allow an object argument for `slideUp()`, that's exactly what I was thinking during my lunch break, also I decided a single callback run would be best instead of one per element so your solution is exactly what I needed, Thanks.